# MongoDB find intersection between two query results

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection in MongoDB:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  from: "from1",
  to: "to1"
},
{ _id: 2,
  from: "from1",
  to: "to2"
},
{ _id: 3,
  from: "from2",
  to: "to1"
},
{
  _id: 4,
  from: "from1",
  to: "to3"
},
{ _id: 5,
  from: "from2",
  to: "to2"
},
{ _id: 6,
  from: "from3",
  to: "to1"
},
```

If I have to lists:

```
f1 = ["from1", "from3"]
f2 = ["from2"]
```

I want to find all "to" values from the elements in the collection where "from" is in each list of "from" values and then from this result find the intersection of "to" values.

E.g.
If I do the following queries:

```
db.collection.find({"from": {"$in": f1}}, {"to": 1, "_id": 0})
db.collection.find({"from": {"$in": f2}}, {"to": 1, "_id": 0})
```

I get these two results:

```
result1 = [{"to": "to1"}, {"to": "to2"}, {"to": "to3"}]
result2 = [{"to": "to1"}, {"to": "to2"}]
```

Now, what I want is the intersection of these 2 results, preferably  in a list:

```
["to1", "to2"]
```

Is there a single query that allows me to obtain this result? I'm using mongodb v3.2 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `$facet` inside your aggregation. It will allow us to run 2 separate `$match` queries and then combine the results, which will make it easy to compare and find that intersection you're looking for. So here is the aggregation you need:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "query1": [
        {
          $match: {
            "from": {
              "$in": ["from1", "from3"] // <- Match Query One
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            tos: {
              $push: "$to"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "query2": [
        {
          $match: {
            "from": {
              "$in": ["from2"] // <- Match Query Two
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            tos: {
              $push: "$to"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$query1"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$query2"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      toIntersection: {
        "$setIntersection": [
          "$query1.tos",
          "$query2.tos"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The result will be this:

```
[
  {
    "toIntersection": [
      "to1",
      "to2"
    ]
  }
]
```

Which, assuming you use node, you can assign to a variable like so:

```
const intersction = result[0].toIntersection; //<-- gives you ["to1", "to2"]
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rs_EO-voAmd

Comment: Yes this solution does exactly what I wanted! However, it `$facet` is not available for my MongoDB version 3.2. I'll accept is as an answer in any case. Thanks!